# Медленные функции в Android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как вызывать функции работающие продолжительное время. Например: для реализации окна авторизации, когда после нажатия кнопки "Login" программа может надолго зависнуть посылая запрос через интернет.

Comment: Соединения с интернетом все равно не будут выполняться в UI-потоке , иначе вы получите сообщение о ошибке при компиляции . Так что ничего не зависнет при нажатии на кнопку Login.

Answer (score 2):

Все операции , занимающие продолжительное время : загрузка/отправка по сети , обработка данных , сложные вычисления и пр. с длительностью более 5 секунд ( а на самом деле все , что хоть как то способно замедлить интерфейс ) , должно быть вынесено из основного (графического) потока в асинхронные .
Андроид имеет собственную реализацию организации асинхронных потоков , которая позволяет эффективно взаимодействовать с основным (графическим) потоком , так как обращения напрямую к UI из других потоков невозможно . Это класс `AsyncTask`.

При реализации этого класса необходимо переопределить четыре метода:

`doInBackground()` - собственно здесь размещается код , который должен выполняться в асинхронном потоке.Он не имеет доступа к UI-потоку.

Следующие три метода , служат для взаимодействия с UI-потоком:
`onPreExecute()` – выполняется перед doInBackground()
`onPostExecute()` – выполняется после doInBackground()
`onProgressUpdate()` - выполняется в процессе выполнения асинхронной задачи. Здесь можно показывать промежуточные результаты , прогрессбар и тп.

Так же класс `AsyncTask`, естественно , может принимать параметры на обработку и возвращать обработанные данные .

Другим способом организации многопоточности в Android является классическая реализация Java - класс `Thread` для собственно открытия потока и класс `Handler` для его взаимодействия с главным (графическим) потоком.

Оба эти способа имеют некоторые ограничения , как то очередь на выполнение следующего потока , что иногда несколько усложняет практическое использование этих инструментов , так как  потоки при открытии встают в очередь и ожидают , пока тот , что был запущен ранее не закончит работу .

Для организации "истинной многозадачности" необходимо использовать вместо вызова `execute` , вызов потока через `executeOnExecutor` , который не связан никакими ограничениями .

```
// обычный вызов
new MyAsyncTask().execute(); 

 //выполнение нескольких задач последовательно:
 new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
 new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);


 //выполнение нескольких задач паралельно:
 new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Так же в андроид есть более специализированные классы , выполняющие асинхронные задачи , например `CursorLoader` который асинхронно загружает курсор выборкой из БД и дополнительно управляет жизненным циклом курсора .

Если вы будете пытаться выполнять сетевые операции (работа с интернет) в главном потоке , то начиная с android 3.0 получите экзепшен 
`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` , который не даст вам заниматься таким безобразием . Начиная с Honeycomb все сетевые операции должны выполняться только в дополнительном потоке и никак иначе.

Дополнительное чтение:

Оффициальная [документация](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) андроид по асинхронным потокам.
[Пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html) работы с `AsyncTask`.
[Пример](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/thread.php) работы с `Thread` в Андроид.
[Что за проблемы](http://dolbodub.blogspot.ru/2013/03/asynctask.html) с потоками в Андроид

Answer (score 0):

Проще, думаю, будет сделать пустой **AsyncTask** в коем вызвать

```
//"Усыпить" поток на 3000 миллисекунд
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

При этом до вызова **AsyncTask** начать анимацию процесса (**ProgressBar**, например).

А после "пробуждения" потока в **AsyncTask** вызовется **onPostExecute()**, коий прекратит анимацию прогресса.

А вот вызвать в главном потоке "медленны" методы не рекомендуется - приложение упадёт по ANR после, вроде, 5 секунд.