# Что не так в коде?

Tags: java, android

Пишу клиента который отправляет фото и видео файлы.

1. Желаемое поведение: программа должна отправлять фалы на сервер.
2. Проблема или ошибка: при нажатии кнопки отправить приложение закрывается.
3. Минимальный код для её воспроизведения:

   ```
   public void onClickSend(View view) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new Thread (new MainActivity()).start();
   }


     @Override
     public void run() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
       int in;

       try {
           client = new Socket("172.16.130.100", 60000);
           input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photo_and_Video/i.jpg"));
           output = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

           while ((in = input.read(byteArray)) != -1){
               output.write(byteArray,0,in);
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       try {
           input.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
           output.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: как минимум, у вас скорее всего не верный путь к файлу. отсюда и FileNotFoundException

Comment: логи еще было бы неплохо показать

Comment: Как-то странно - вы передаете потоку new MainActivity(). У вас активность реализует интерфейс Runnable?

Comment: @iramm да всё как полагается MainActivity implement Runeble, данный способ пробовал в eclipse только поток был в методе main и всё работает. Прикручиваю данный клиент к кнопке на Android и результат описан выше.

Comment: @Chaynik а как правильно его прописать, то что в коде я его с телефона переписывал вроде всё верно начинается с корневой директории.

Comment: @whalemare логов нет сервак самопальный буквально утром написан.

Comment: Было бы интересно посмотреть на весь ваш MainActivity.

Comment: Создавать новый поток из активити абсолютно неправильно. Делайте в дополнительном потоке только метод, который должен выполнять требуемые асинхронные действия. Созданием и управлением активити занимается система, програмисту туда вмешиваться черевато только труднодиагностируемыми поблемами

Comment: @pavlofff я не всё понял, а точнее подскажите на примере как это осуществить ?

Comment: Смотрите, например, [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418832/177345) (и примеры в конце)  по организации асинхронных вызовов в Android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не видя весь ваш код и стэктрэйс ошибки, рискну сделать предположение, что проблемы вызваны созданием активности с помощью конструктора `new MainActivity()`. Это абсолютно не в духе Android. Активность создает сама ОС, а наше дело заполнить методы жизненного цикла активности (`onCreate()`, `onResume()` ...), которые так же вызовет ОС в подходящий момент.

Мое предложение: Зачем вам, чтобы активность реализовывала `Runnable`. Попробуйте сделать более привычно, например, так:

```
public void onClickSend(View view) throws FileNotFoundException {
   new Thread (
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // Здесь содержимое вашего метода run()
        })
  .start();
}
```

Comment: Да здесь опеделенно страшный архитектурный ужас в вопросе. Тут надо не о предположениях и предложениях говорить, а категорически требовать :)

Comment: @ iramm в остальном коде 2 кнопки фото и видео и они работают то есть видео снимается и фото делаются сохраняя результат в указанную папку. Проблема в отправке этот код что я привёл за неё и отвечает повторюсь что без Андройда он работает, вопрос как его посадить на кнопку "отправить", спасибо что вы мне привели пример, но он не работает так как когда пешим  implement Runeble метод run создаётся автоматом в этом же классе, но отдельно от других методов, вы предлагаете его прописать внутри другого метода, что вызывает ошибку.

Comment: @pavlofff ха-ха-ха согласен с требованиями, но знаний не хватает. Скажите чем архитектура не нравиться ?

Comment: @VargSieg Вроде бы довольно доступно объяснило несколько человек ранее, что нельзя создавать экземпляры активити самому и нельзя  запускать целиком всю активити в отдельном потоке. Используйте класс `AsyncTask` например, для выполнения асинхронных задач.

Comment: @pavlofff эх было бы доступно я бы не переспрашивал. 1) что вы имеете ввиду под экземпляры активити данное выражение new Thread (new MainActivity()).start(); ? 2) нельзя запускать целиком всю активити это как понять я всегда думал что нажимаю кнопку "отправить" запускается поток далее метод run.

Comment: @VargSieg То, что у вас там работало что то в Core Java на Эклипсе ни о чем не говорит. Активити [очень сложный](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity) механизм, управляемый системой и действия, подобные `new MainActivity()).start()`  неприемлемы для нее, как и имплементация интерфейсов, как `Runnable`. Может вам и кажется ваше решение гениальным, но кроме вас так никто не делает по вполне банальным причинам - это неправильно и работать не будет.

Comment: @pavlofff Да не кажется мне это решение гениальным ))) я не на чём не настаиваю, это просто всё что у меня есть из моих знаний))) На сколько опыт позволяет на столько и пишу )) "Активити очень сложный механизм, управляемый системой и действия" и что теперь программы не писать )))

Comment: @VargSieg Так и есть, не надо такого в программах на андроид писать. О том, как правильно писать, есть ссылка в моем [последнем комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533807/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5/533935?noredirect=1#comment669086_533807) под вашим вопросом, кроме того выпущено большое количество литературы по разработке под андроид и всевозможных гайдов. Так что оправдываться, что не знаю как, во времена безлимитного интернета несколько наивно.